# Load image from URL on button click

Tags: java, android, url, imageview

I have this ImageView that displays a picture from a URL. I want to have a button that when clicked will display the image from the URL. Could anyone teach me how to do this?

Here's my code:

```js
 String url = "https://www.google.com.ph/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&ved=0ahUKEwiGzJm-l5PWAhVJl5QKHegTAg0QjBwIBA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.enterprise.co.uk%2Fcontent%2Fdam%2Fglobal-vehicle-images%2Fcars%2FVAUX_INSI_2014.png&psig=AFQjCNGerQpF4NHcx50OFhQ2AGUlJYQCpQ&ust=1504877444951754";
    ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        loadImageFromUrl(url);
    }

    private void loadImageFromUrl(String url) {
        Picasso.with(this) .load(url) .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .into(imageView, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError() {

                    }
                });
    }
```

Picasso:

```js
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

Comment: can you provide your Picasso dependency version as well which you have used in build.gradle file

Comment: the URL which you have. It doesn't have a image in it. Check

Answer (score 0):

Called when a view has been clicked.

```
imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Do something here
            loadImageFromUrl(url);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a button to your xml file. Let it be with id: btn_load;

Inside the activity add

```
Button btn = findViewById(R.id.btn_load);
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        loadImageFromUrl(url);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a button in your xml layout file. Then in onCreate call:

```
final String url = "https://www.google.com.ph/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&ved=0ahUKEwiGzJm-l5PWAhVJl5QKHegTAg0QjBwIBA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.enterprise.co.uk%2Fcontent%2Fdam%2Fglobal-vehicle-images%2Fcars%2FVAUX_INSI_2014.png&psig=AFQjCNGerQpF4NHcx50OFhQ2AGUlJYQCpQ&ust=1504877444951754";
ImageView imageView;
Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    button = findViewById(R.id.button_id);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            loadImageFromUrl(url);    
        }
    });
}
```

Note: for this to work you will have to declare your url String as *final*, because you're using it inside an anonymous class (OnClickListener).

Note2: The image url you have may not work. Use this one instead: https://www.enterprise.co.uk/content/dam/global-vehicle-images/cars/VAUX_INSI_2014.png